# Como Actualizar el banner del usuario o el avatar

Tags: php, pdo

Hola esto tratando de actualizar los datos en una de mis tablas mediante este codigo

```
<?php
session_start();
$user_id = $_GET['usuario'];
include('db.php')
if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
    if(isset($_FILES['avatar'])){
        if($_FILES['avatar'] != ""){
            $image = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
            $client_id=" ";
            $handle = fopen($image, "r");
            $data = fread($handle, filesize($image));
            $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data));
            $timeout = 30;
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);
            $pms = json_decode($out,true);
            $url=$pms['data']['link'];
            $_SESSION['av'] = $url;  
            //insert into database with a prepared statement  banner
            $stmt = $connection->query("UPDATE user SET avatar = '".$url."' WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'  ");

            $stmt->execute();

            header("Location:https://miweb.com/".$user_id);
            exit;
        }

    }//Aqui va el mismo codigo que arriba pero para el banner
}
?>
```

ahora bien este codigo funciona perfectamente a la hora de cargar las imagenes pero me gustaría que permitiera al usuario elegir si subir un banner (portada) o actualizar el avatar intente usando `!isset(), isset() y empy()` pero ninguno me dio resultado, alguien tiene idea de como hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro de entender bien tu pregunta, pero si veo que hay un error de concepto en tu código, siempre y cuando tu formulario en el front esté presente el input type=file avatar en el servidor se recibirá el $_FILES['avatar'] con un array con las keys 'name', 'tmp_name', etc pero valores vacíos o llenos dependiendo si el usuario ha seleccionado o no un archivo, pero nunca viene vacío.

Entonces deberías cambiar tu línea:

```
if($_FILES['avatar'] != ""){
// por esta, comprobando una de los valores
if($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'] != ""){
```